# Google API Visualization Chart Not Working

Tags: javascript, graph, google-visualization

I used the Google Visualization API for making 3 graphs but only 1 graph is showing. However, when I refresh the page or go to a different browser, a different graph appears. How do I make every graph appear? I used @WhiteHat suggestion but it did not work. Here is the updated code after their suggestion:

```
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-66892235-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Analysis Tool</title>

{% load staticfiles %}

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/grayscale.css' %}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/style.css' %}" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="{% static 'home/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
```

```
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 

<script type="text/javascript">



    function printDiv(divName) {
        var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
        console.log(printContents)
        w=window.open();
        w.document.write("<html><head><title>Print Page</title>");
        w.document.write("{% load staticfiles %}")
        w.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}' />")
        w.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static 'home/css/style.css' %}' />")
        w.document.write("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>")
        w.document.write('</head><body>');
        w.document.write(printContents);
        w.document.write('</body></html>');
        w.print();
        w.close();  
    }       


    // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.        
    google.charts.load('current', {callback: drawChart,packages: ['bar', 'corechart', 'line', 'table'] });

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        var djangoDataTable = {{ tableArr|safe }};
        var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoDataTable);

        var djangoData1 = {{ deathHBV_Final|safe }}
        var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoData1);

        var djangoData2 = {{ hcc_Final|safe }}
        var data2 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoData2);

        var djangoData3 = {{ cirrhosis_Final|safe }}
        var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoData3);



        var options3 = {
            title: "Mortality Rate HBV",
            titleTextStyle :{
                fontSize:26,
                fontName:'Raleway',
            },
            colors: ['#ff7f50','#49B7A8'],

            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            vAxis: {
                title:'Percentage (%)',
                maxValue: 100,
            },
            hAxis:{
                title:'Year',
            },
            legend:{
                position:'none',
                maxLines: 2,
            }
        };

        var options4 = {
            title: "Cirrhosis",
            titleTextStyle :{
                fontSize:26,
                fontName:'Raleway',
            },
            colors: ['#ff7f50','#49B7A8'],
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            vAxis: {
                title:'Percentage (%)',
                maxValue: 100,
            },
            hAxis:{
                title:'Year',
            },
            legend:{
                position:'none',
                maxLines: 2,
            }
        };

        var options5 = {
            title: "Liver Cancer",
            titleTextStyle :{
                fontSize:26,
                fontName:'Raleway',
            },
            colors: ['#ff7f50','#49B7A8'],

            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            vAxis: {
                title:'Percentage (%)',
                maxValue: 100,
            },
            hAxis:{
                title:'Year',
            },
            legend:{
                position:'none',
                maxLines: 2,
            }
        };

        var optionsTable = {
            'showRowNumber': false,
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'allowHtml': true, 
        };

        var chart3 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart1'));
        chart3.draw(data1, options3);

        if({{ ifCirr }} == 0){
            var chart4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart2'));
            chart4.draw(data3, options4);
        }

        var chart5 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart3'));
        chart5.draw(data2, options5);

        for (y = 0; y < 4; y++){
            dataTable.setCell(y,0,String(djangoDataTable[y+1][0]),null,{'style': ' font-size:20px;'})
        }

        for (j = 1; j < djangoDataTable[1].length; j += 2){
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
                dataTable.setCell(i,j,String(djangoDataTable[i+1][j]),null,{'style': 'background-color: rgba(255,127,80,0.7); font-size:18px;'})
            }
        }

        for (j = 2; j < djangoDataTable[1].length; j += 2){
            for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
                dataTable.setCell(i,j,String(djangoDataTable[i+1][j]),null,{'style': 'background-color: #49b7a8; font-size:18px;'})
            }
        }

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
        table.draw(dataTable, optionsTable);
    }

    $('#mailform').submit(function(){
        var formAction = $("#selectmail").val() == "technical" ? "research.cs.alc@gmail.com" : "mtoy@stanford.edu";
        $("#mailform").attr("action", "MAILTO:" + formAction);
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

first, it is recommended to use `loader.js` vs. the older library `jsapi`.

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`
vs.
`<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`

next, the `load` statement should only be called once per page load.
which is probably the reason for random chart selection.
and you can load all the `packages` you need in one call.

try replacing this...

```
// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.load('visualization', '1.1',{'packages': ['line']});
google.load("visualization", "1.0", {'packages':['table']});
// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
```

with this...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar', 'corechart', 'line', 'table']
});
```

Comment: I realized the error is with my hosting website. Your code works! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey I hosted it and I am still getting the error. It worked once but with a different form input, it doesn't. Let me know what I should do.

Comment: I am using Heroku and I think it is very slow. Do you think that is a problem?

Comment: Nevermind I hadn't updated the code to the master file. I will try again

Comment: In my GitHub there are a blocks of red highlighted code. I tried re-formatting it but that didn't work. What should I do?

Comment: sorry, can't get to GitHub from current location. do you have a specific error message? or maybe update the question with the latest code...

Comment: Here is a screenshot: https://gyazo.com/b4c402d33b520f3d1b1194bc9aade4e4

Comment: hmm, all that seems fine. did you check the console for errors? press F12 in the browser and look at the console tab...