# Google Visualization API Graphs

Tags: javascript, heroku, google-api, google-visualization, pygooglechart

I have used the Google Visualization API tool to make 3 graphs. However, every time I run the code a different graph appears. Also, if I refresh the page or go to a different browser, a different graph appears.

There is also a data table that sometimes appears and sometimes doesn't. I am using a free version of Heroku to host my website. Do you think it has to do with the speed of the page from Heroku? Am I using an updated Google API library? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
        m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-66892235-1', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Analysis Tool</title>

    {% load staticfiles %}

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" />

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/grayscale.css' %}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'home/css/style.css' %}" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="{% static 'home/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.1.min.js" > </script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">



        function printDiv(divName) {
            var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
            console.log(printContents)
            w=window.open();
            w.document.write("<html><head><title>Print Page</title>");
            w.document.write("{% load staticfiles %}")
            w.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static 'home/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}' />")
            w.document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% static 'home/css/style.css' %}' />")
            w.document.write("<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>")
            w.document.write('</head><body>');
            w.document.write(printContents);
            w.document.write('</body></html>');
            w.print();
            w.close();  
        }       


        // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar', 'corechart', 'line', 'table']
});
        // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var djangoDataTable = {{ tableArr|safe }};
            var dataTable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoDataTable);

            var djangoDataDeathHBV = {{ deathHBV_Final|safe }}
            var dataDeathHBV = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoDataDeathHBV);

            var djangoDataHcc = {{ hcc_Final|safe }}
            var dataHcc = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoDataHcc);

            var djangoDataCirrhosis = {{ cirrhosis_Final|safe }}
            var dataCirrhosis = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(djangoDataCirrhosis);



            var MortalityRate = {
                title: "Mortality Rate HBV",
                titleTextStyle :{
                    fontSize:26,
                    fontName:'Raleway',
                },
                colors: ['#ff7f50','#49B7A8'],

                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                vAxis: {
                    title:'Percentage (%)',
                    maxValue: 100,
                },
                hAxis:{
                    title:'Year',
                },
                legend:{
                    position:'none',
                    maxLines: 2,
                }
            };

            var CirrhosisGraph = {
                title: "Cirrhosis",
                titleTextStyle :{
                    fontSize:26,
                    fontName:'Raleway',
                },
                colors: ['#ff7f50','#49B7A8'],
                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                vAxis: {
                    title:'Percentage (%)',
                    maxValue: 100,
                },
                hAxis:{
                    title:'Year',
                },
                legend:{
                    position:'none',
                    maxLines: 2,
                }
            };

            var LiverCancer = {
                title: "Liver Cancer",
                titleTextStyle :{
                    fontSize:26,
                    fontName:'Raleway',
                },
                colors: ['#ff7f50','#49B7A8'],

                width: 400,
                height: 400,
                vAxis: {
                    title:'Percentage (%)',
                    maxValue: 100,
                },
                hAxis:{
                    title:'Year',
                },
                legend:{
                    position:'none',
                    maxLines: 2,
                }
            };

            var optionsTable = {
                'showRowNumber': false,
                'width': '100%',
                'height': '100%',
                'allowHtml': true, 
            };

            var chart3 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart1'));
            chart3.draw(dataDeathHBV, MortalityRate);

            if({{ ifCirr }} == 0){
                var chart4 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart2'));
                chart4.draw(dataCirrhosis, CirrhosisGraph;
            }

            var chart5 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart3'));
            chart5.draw(dataHcc, LiverCancer);

            for (y = 0; y < 4; y++){
                dataTable.setCell(y,0,String(djangoDataTable[y+1][0]),null,{'style': ' font-size:20px;'})
            }

            for (j = 1; j < djangoDataTable[1].length; j += 2){
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
                    dataTable.setCell(i,j,String(djangoDataTable[i+1][j]),null,{'style': 'background-color: rgba(255,127,80,0.7); font-size:18px;'})
                }
            }

            for (j = 2; j < djangoDataTable[1].length; j += 2){
                for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
                    dataTable.setCell(i,j,String(djangoDataTable[i+1][j]),null,{'style': 'background-color: #49b7a8; font-size:18px;'})
                }
            }

            var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));
            table.draw(dataTable, optionsTable);
        }

        $('#mailform').submit(function(){
            var formAction = $("#selectmail").val() == "technical" ? "research.cs.alc@gmail.com" : "mtoy@stanford.edu";
            $("#mailform").attr("action", "MAILTO:" + formAction);
        }); 

    </script>
</head>
```

Here is the Github file too:

https://github.com/MehlikaToy/Django_AnalysisTool/blob/master/backend/templates/markov/results.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google API Visualization Chart Not Working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38339239/google-api-visualization-chart-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `google.load()` once.

[In your file on GitHub](https://github.com/MehlikaToy/Django_AnalysisTool/blob/master/backend/templates/markov/results.html#L75-L79) - lines 75-79 - you're calling `google.load()` multiples times. Instead of this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.load('visualization', '1.1',{'packages': ['line']});
google.load("visualization", "1.0", {'packages':['table']});
```

Try this:

```
google.load('visualization', "1.1", {'packages': ['corechart', 'bar', 'line', 'table']});
```

Comment: Do I still keep: google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

Comment: Yes, but similarly, you can only have one callback.

Comment: Would this work:  google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar', 'corechart', 'line', 'table']
});

Comment: @TejpalVirdi That will work if you change to the gstatic address from the current documentation. The code I saw was using the old jsapi address.